# How to share an Immutable reference of a struct among multiple threads in Rust?

Tags: concurrency, rust, immutability, shared-memory, unsafe

I have a struct which I want to share as an Immutable reference among multiple threads.
I am Using  "Arc" to do that but for Arc to work I have to Implement Send & Sync traits for my struct.
here is the problem, it is written in the Rust Book that Implementing Send and Sync Manually Is Unsafe.

What is the solution for this?

Are there any alternatives to share an Immutable reference among multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

[`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html) and [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) are implemented automatically by the compiler when it is safe to do so. Both documentations state that:

> This trait is automatically implemented when the compiler determines it's appropriate.

The [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/send-and-sync.html) contains more details about what makes a type `Send` or `Sync`, but most types are `Send` except:

> Major exceptions include:
>
> - raw pointers are neither `Send` nor `Sync` (because they have no safety guards).
> - `UnsafeCell` isn't `Sync` (and therefore `Cell` and `RefCell` aren't).
> - `Rc` isn't `Send` or `Sync` (because the refcount is shared and unsynchronized).

Plus, all types that contain only `Send` fields are automatically `Send` too. So all you need is for your custom structs to only contain `Send` fields and you should be fine.